# How can I send notifications from my Java server to my react-native client in realtime?

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I would like to send messages from my Java server to my react-native clients.

I don't know exactly how to solve this. Should the server establish a connection to all clients via the IP addresses of the clients and send the message and then close the connection again? (Sounds the most sensible to me.)

I think that would be better than if the clients connected to the server and the connection should always be maintained. After all, it should run with high performance.

Basically, it doesn't make much sense for my system that the clients connect to the server, since only the server knows when and whether it is sending a message.

I've already tried working with websockets. However, it didn't seem to work without requests from clients.

The difficulty is to find a method that works with Java on the server side and JavaScript on the client side and that the connection is made from the server to the clients and not from the clients to the server. In addition, the transmission should work in real time.

Is that feasible? Are there any better ways? How can I do it?

I hope you can help me.

Greetings. Martin

[The basic function of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLq9q.png)

Comment: Using websockets is the only way to send messages from the server to the client in real-time. The client has to initiate (and re-establish) the connection but I don't see how that's an issue. As soon as your React app mounts, it establishes a connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple cloud based messaging platforms. One of them is Firebase from Google which is free (I guess). Check this out here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

You will find multiple tutorials to configure and use it in your react-native and Java server.

Architectural overview: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture

Another solution is writing your own logic using the WebSockets.

Lifecycle of message: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture#lifecycle_flow

Comment: I have never really dealt with firebase because, as far as I know, you have to host there with Google and I cannot run the system on my servers.

How can I build this structure myself? Is it possible to transfer the data via HTTP without a request from the clients or are there other protocols for data transfer without a request from the clients? I just need the same system as with Firebase, just not as complex.

With websockets, the request is only a registration option so that the server knows that the client exists. But I don't need that because I have the IP addresses of the clients.